# Html Click on both siblings while using z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, mouseclick-event

I have a two div which HAVE to be displayed above each others using z-index;

Both however have to react to the same click event as if the event was propergated from a child to a parent.

Is this possible in any way?

here is an example

```
<body>
  <div id="upper" style=" position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #000"></div>
  <div id="lower" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 120px; height: 120px; background-color: #00f"></div>
</body>
```

Both should be listening to native click events since the lower sibling could hold an iframe.

EDIT For More Clerifications

The Goal is to make the youtube iframe in this example clickable as well as keep all the controls on the canvas element.
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#1DX9UE#51

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit JS solution or would a CSS be fine as well?

Comment: Can `pointer-events: none` on upper element do the job?

Comment: Why can't you just wrap these two divs in a parent div, and then base your click event on the parent?

Comment: `pointer-events: none` is sadly not sufficient since both elements needs to react to the pointer events only difference is that higher object is not beeing triggered at the x and y positions of the lower one.
The higher one is a canvas width a whole at the position of the lower one and the lower one is going to be anything including an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Just write a Javascript event listener to click the other button when one is clicked.

```
document.getElementById('upper').addEvenListener('click', () => {
console.log('parent clicked')
})
document.getElementById('lower').addEvenListener('click', () => {
document.getElementById('upper').click()
})
```

Comment: as mentioned this is sadly not enough since the lower element might house an iframe and i have no controle over how this element handles the clicks inside.

I need to propergate the exact native click event if possible.